# AesCryptoServiceProvider.TransformFinalBlock error: The input data is not a complete block

Tags: c#, aes

I wrote what was supposed to be a simple encrypt/decrypt application to familiarize myself with the AesCryptoServiceProvider and I am receiving an error.  The error is "The input data is not a complete block."  Here is the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter string to encrypt:");
        string userText = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] key;
        byte[] IV;
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            key = aes.Key;
            IV = aes.IV;
        }

        byte[] encryptedText = EncryptString(userText, key, IV);

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedText));

        string decryptedText = DecryptString(encryptedText, key, IV);

        Console.WriteLine(decryptedText);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static byte[] EncryptString(string encryptText, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider symAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            symAlg.Key = key;
            symAlg.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform ct = symAlg.CreateEncryptor(symAlg.Key, symAlg.IV);
            byte[] encryptTextBytes = UnicodeEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptText);
            byte[] encryptedText = ct.TransformFinalBlock(encryptTextBytes, 0, encryptTextBytes.Length);

            return encryptTextBytes;
        }
    }

    private static string DecryptString(byte[] decryptText, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider symAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            symAlg.Key = key;
            symAlg.IV = IV;
            ICryptoTransform ct = symAlg.CreateDecryptor(symAlg.Key, symAlg.IV);
            byte[] decryptedUserText = ct.TransformFinalBlock(decryptText, 0, decryptText.Length);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedUserText);
        }
    }
```

I can find results for this error online but they are all related to writing to a memory stream for encryption, which is not really what I am doing. Can someone help point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You forgot to pad the input to a full block? Encryption usually works only on blocks of a specific size, so the last block has to be filled with stuff so it is of the required size.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Is that something that is typically done as a part of the encryption or the decryption? And, is there a baked-in way to do it, or something I need to do manually?

Comment: AESCryptoprovide has something, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding.aspx . But this is something you really need to look up specific to the algos and implementation you use, as a bad padding could compromise your whole system (unlikely, but why risk it?).

Comment: Well, I saw that property but it is set by default to a padding mode (PaddingMode.PKCS7).  Even if I manually try the other padding modes in the enum it still doesn't work.  Seems like if that is set it should "just work", but I'm obviously green at this so I could be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha, found it!
Look at what you return in your encrypt function:

```
        byte[] encryptTextBytes = UnicodeEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptText);
        byte[] encryptedText = ct.TransformFinalBlock(encryptTextBytes, 0, encryptTextBytes.Length);

        return encryptTextBytes;
```

Tip: it is not the encrypted stuff.

Comment: Ugh...as usual better variable names would have saved me heartache.  Thanks!