# the input data is not a complete block while decrypting the cipher Text

Tags: c#

can anyone help me where is the problem?
Here is the Decrypt function code.

```
    public  static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText)
    {
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        String key = "0102030405060708";
        String iv = "1020304050607080";
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] bytearraytodecrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cipherText);


        AesCryptoServiceProvider keydecrypt = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        keydecrypt.BlockSize = 128;
        keydecrypt.KeySize = 128;
        keydecrypt.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        keydecrypt.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
        keydecrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        keydecrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        ICryptoTransform crypto1 = keydecrypt.CreateDecryptor(keydecrypt.Key, keydecrypt.IV);

        byte[] returnbytearray = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(bytearraytodecrypt, 0, bytearraytodecrypt.Length);
        crypto1.Dispose();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(returnbytearray);
    }
```

Comment: What problem/error message are you experiencing?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, The error message I am getting is this " the input data is not a complete block ".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092814/aescryptoserviceprovider-transformfinalblock-error-the-input-data-is-not-a-comp

Answer (score 1):

hi Here is the code after the modifications and it works fine. 
The changes I made to the previous code is converting the cipher text from Base64 string to the bytes format and at last while returning the String convert it to the System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString format.

```
public  static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText)
{
    if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");

    String key = "0102030405060708";
    String iv = "1020304050607080";

    if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

    if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

    byte[] bytearraytodecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    AesCryptoServiceProvider keydecrypt = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    keydecrypt.BlockSize = 128;
    keydecrypt.KeySize = 128;
    keydecrypt.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    keydecrypt.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
    keydecrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    keydecrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    ICryptoTransform crypto1 = keydecrypt.CreateDecryptor(keydecrypt.Key, keydecrypt.IV);

    byte[] returnbytearray = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(bytearraytodecrypt, 0, bytearraytodecrypt.Length);
    crypto1.Dispose();
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returnbytearray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is.

AES in CBC mode is a block cipher, that is the input and output is in block sized chunks.

If the input to encryption might not always be a multiple of the block size padding can be added (PKCS#7 padding in the question code) to the data to be encrypted to make it so. The output will be a multiple of the block size.

Because of this the question does not make sense, the encrypted data will always be a multiole of the block size if PKCS#7 padding is used (as in the code).

On decryption the decrypted output will be a multiple of the block size and then the padding can be removed.

By specifying PKCS#7 padding int he APIU call the padding/de-padding will happen in the API.

There are other modes such as CTR where the output is the same length as the input, they are in general "streaming" modes and have their own complications such as never using the same nonce with the same key.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error in the below line of code.

byte[] returnbytearray = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(bytearraytodecrypt, 0, bytearraytodecrypt.Length);
And the Error is " the input data is not a complete block"
The input cipher text I am passing to the above function is this: aTIqjIwgjyAbNFT+aBSjW8+U1SAPI+GMaZjPlVixEJU=

Comment: The encrypted data supplied is Base64 which is 44 bytes. But in general encryption and decryption expects data byte, you need to decode the Base64 string to 64 bytes for decryption. For examination the 64 bytes in hex: 69322A8C8C208F201B3454FE6814A35BCF94D5200F23E18C6998CF9558B11095. The other error still need to be corrected. Also it helps if you also supply the expected decrypted data.

Comment: Hi Zaph, Thanks for the answer.I have converted the cipher text to the byte array and it works.The code I added to the above function is this:
 byte[] bytearraytodecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);